# JQuery in Internet Explorer - Selecting Table Columns

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, internet-explorer-8, formatting

I'm trying to do some dynamic resizing of table columns on my page.  Everything works fine in FF and Chrome, but (as usual) it seems to be breaking in Internet Explorer.  After a lot of debugging, I've found that the problem is caused by JQuery selectors don't work correctly in Internet Explorer, when you're dealing with tables.  It would appear that if you are trying to select a column in a multi-row table, JQuery will only select the first column.  Here is some quick code that will show the problem.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("td#2").css('background-color', 'red');  
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr><td id="1">1</td><td id="2">2</td></tr>
<tr><td id="1">1</td><td id="2">2</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

You will notice that in IE, only the first "2" is highlighted.  It should (if I understand my own code correctly) highlight both of the 2's.  Any ideas for workaround in this?

Comment: id attribute must be unique in html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of an ID (which has to be **unique**, your current issue), use a `class` and `$("td.2")`, or neither...and use [`:nth-child()`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/), like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("td:nth-child(2)").css('background-color', 'red');  
});
```

With this your markup gets much simpler:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Z5gq2/) - and for comparison, [here's the class version](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Z5gq2/1/).

Comment: Thanks Nick!  That specific problem ended up being something else (I had some css from a container div that was screwing me up), but I used your tip to fix a lot of other bugs in my page!  Silly me, teching myself HTML/CSS/JS I never learned that ID's needed to be unique.  Oops!